# Can't plot derivative of Hankel function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, complex

I am trying to plot the first derivative of $H^{(1)}_3 (ix)$ with respect to its argument $ix$, where $H^{(1)}_3 (ix)$ is the [Hankel function of the first kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HankelFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) with order $3$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is a real variable and $i = \sqrt{-1}$ is the imaginary unit.

According to the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), it should be:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}(ix)} \left[ H^{(1)}_3 (ix) \right] = \frac{1}{i} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left[ H^{(1)}_3 (ix) \right]$$

So, first, I defined:

```
a[x_] := HankelH1[3, I*x];
```

It is a real-valued function and it's easy to plot, for example with `Plot[a[X], {X, 0, 10}]`.

Then:

```
b[x_] := D[a[x], x];
```

which is pure imaginary and should represent $\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left[ H^{(1)}_3 (ix) \right]$. Then,

```
c[x_] := D[a[x], x] / I;
```

should be $\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}(ix)} \left[ H^{(1)}_3 (ix) \right]$ and should be real.

However, I can't plot it:

```
Plot[c[X], {X, 0, 10}]
```

gives

```
General::ivar: 0.0002042857142857143` is not a valid variable.
General::ivar: 0.20428591836734694` is not a valid variable.
General::ivar: 0.40836755102040817` is not a valid variable.
General::stop: Further output of General::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

Why? What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Mathematica 12.0.0 on Linux x86 (64 bit).

Comment: Use [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative) instead, e.g., ``Derivative[0,1][HankelH1][3, I x]/I``.

Comment: It works with `Derivative`! And yes, the reason is the same as in the linked question. Thank you!