# Why doesn't plotting a derivative work?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

If I plot a derivative it fails:
`Plot[ D[x^2 + 1, x], {x, -6., 6.}]`
General::ivar: -5.99975 is not a valid variable.

But if I simply put the derivative, 2x, in, the plot works:
`Plot[2x,{x,-.6,.6}]`

Most other standard functions don't do this. Why doesn't plotting a derivative work, and what  is the "..valid variable" warning about?

Comment: There is another question just a bit before about the same question. That is how popular it is. Did you check the search box here for "why plot derivative", for example ? You can get answers a lot faster and with less effort by searching. Searching  what I mentioned before I found [Can't plot derivative of Hankel function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/235317/86543). Since this question is very popular it already had a duplicate

Comment: which was [General:ivar.... how to avoid it](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/generalivar-is-not-a-valid-variable-when-plotting-what-actually-causes-this)

Comment: Oddly enough, I discovered using ' instead of D does work, which that article does not answer. 
f[x_] := x^2 + 1
Plot[f'[x], {x, -5, 5}] --Works
Plot[D[f[x], x], {x, -5, 5}] --Fails

Comment: I got rid of set delayed after reading the article but got the same result D fails, and ' works, which makes no sense to me. The Help on Hold is really mysterious. Doesn't say much.

Comment: Hi, that answer does explain why `f'[x]` works when `D[f[x],x]` does not. During the plot `x` is replaced directly by one of the values in the range specified. For example, starting at `x=-5` it will evaluate `D[f[-5],-5]` which is not valid as you can't take the derivative of a number. However `f'[-5]` is fine whether you evaluate it your self or `Plot` evaluates it. `f'[x]` and `D[f[x],x]` have the same output but they are encoded differently. To see that you can use `//HoldForm//FullForm` on both.

Comment: In particular, you can evaluate `f'` without choosing an argument and it will output the derivative as a function (you can try with `f[x_]:=x^3`). Hence basically, `f'[4]` is basically the same as `g=f'; g[4]` and there is no problem in plotting `g[x]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [General::ivar is not a valid variable when plotting - what actually causes this and how to avoid it?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/generalivar-is-not-a-valid-variable-when-plotting-what-actually-causes-this)

Answer (score 2):

Using `With`:

```
With[{f = D[x^2 + 1, x]}, Plot[f, {x, -6, 6}]]
```

Or using `HoldForm` as points out @userrandrand:

```
ReleaseHold@HoldForm[Plot][D[x^2 + 1, x], {x, -6, 6}]
```

Comment: Hi. I did not mention using `HoldForm` like that but that's a possibility. Although the idea of controlling the evaluation order is similar, I think it's quicker to use `Plot[D[x^2+1,x]//Evaluate,{x,-6,6}]`. Another possibility is `D[x^2 + 1, x] // Plot[#, {x, -6, 6}] &`. That last option is particularly convenient if there a lot of functions that will be plotted in the same interval in which case  one can set `plt=Plot[#, {x, -6, 6}] &` and use `D[x^2 + 1, x] //plt` then `D[x^4 + 1, x] //plt`

Comment: Hi. True, you didn't mention using `HoldForm` in that way, but I thought you were thinking of that. In fact, `D[x^2 + 1, x] // Plot[#, {x, -6, 6}] &` is a better way. :-)

Comment: Another way is `plt2 = OperatorApplied[Plot]` then `D[x^2 + 1, x] // plt2[{x, -6, 6}]` which could be convenient for changing the interval.

Comment: @userrandrand - or more concisely, `Plot @@ {D[x^2 + 1, x], {x, -6, 6}}`

Comment: @BobHanlon that one is quite beautiful. Feels like something I should save in a corner of my log on screen . Quite pretty.