# Plotting D of Sin fails but ' of Sin does not

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, evaluation

I understand why you have to use Evaluate with D to make it work, but why then does the apostrophe form work for Derivate without Evaluate?

If I plot a derivative one way I get an error - and yes, I know I have to use Evaluate:
Plot[D[Sin[x], x], {x, -6., 6.}]
General::ivar: -5.99975 is not a valid variable.

But if I plot with an apostrophe it gives me the Cosine plot without Evaluate.
Plot[Sin'[x], {x, -6., 6.}]

And I know Mathematica thinks they are identical since
D[Sin[x], x] == Sin'[x] gives me True

Comment: Please read the comments you receive carefully: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/274501/why-doesnt-plotting-a-derivative-work#comment685322_274501

Comment: Note that results being identical does not mean that the codes are identical. (And as discussed in the linked Q&A in the first comment above, `Plot` evaluates the code first setting `x` to a numeric value and does not evaluate the results of `D[Sin[x], x]` and `Sin'[x]` you see when `x` is an undefined symbol.)

Comment: To make it more obvious: try `x = 1; D[Sin[x], x] == Sin'[x]`.